# WebService usando SOAP WSDL en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, webservice, wsdl

Saludos a toda la comunidad.

Estoy tratando de crear un servicio de consulta usando SOAP WSDL con Laravel, he estado indagando y he encontrado la librería laravel https://packagist.org/packages/artisaninweb/laravel-soap

El asunto es que tengo la impresión que los datos de autenticación no están funcionando bien, he tratado con varios métodos pero no esto muy seguro de que es lo que esta fallando, quiero depurar lo que he hecho hasta ahora antes de tratar de hacerlo completamente a mano. Les muestro:

**XML con los datos que debería enviar**

```
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
   xmlns:mrw="http://www.mrw.es/">
   <soap:Header>
  <mrw:AuthInfo>
    <mrw:CodigoFranquicia>003088</mrw:CodigoFranquicia>
     <mrw:CodigoAbonado>0033038</mrw:CodigoAbonado>
     <mrw:CodigoDepartamento></mrw:CodigoDepartamento>
     <mrw:UserName>Usuario</mrw:UserName>
     <mrw:Password>Password</mrw:Password>
  </mrw:AuthInfo>
   </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
  <mrw:TransmEnvio>
     <mrw:request>
        <mrw:DatosRecogida>
           <mrw:Direccion>
              <mrw:CodigoTipoVia></mrw:CodigoTipoVia>
              <mrw:Via></mrw:Via>
              <mrw:Numero></mrw:Numero>
              <mrw:Resto></mrw:Resto>
              <mrw:CodigoPostal></mrw:CodigoPostal>
              <mrw:Poblacion></mrw:Poblacion>
              <mrw:Provincia></mrw:Provincia>
              <mrw:CodigoPais></mrw:CodigoPais>
           </mrw:Direccion>
           <mrw:Nif></mrw:Nif>
           <mrw:Nombre></mrw:Nombre>
           <mrw:Telefono></mrw:Telefono>
           <mrw:Contacto></mrw:Contacto>
           <mrw:Observaciones></mrw:Observaciones>
        </mrw:DatosRecogida>
        <mrw:DatosEntrega>
           <mrw:Direccion>
              <mrw:CodigoTipoVia>CALLE</mrw:CodigoTipoVia>
              <mrw:Via>CORCEGA</mrw:Via>
              <mrw:Numero>102</mrw:Numero>
              <mrw:Resto>PISO 4B </mrw:Resto>
              <mrw:CodigoPostal>08029</mrw:CodigoPostal>
              <mrw:Poblacion>BARCELONA</mrw:Poblacion>
              <mrw:Provincia></mrw:Provincia>
              <mrw:CodigoPais>ES</mrw:CodigoPais>
           </mrw:Direccion>
           <mrw:Nif></mrw:Nif>
           <mrw:Nombre>PRUEBA INTEGRACION MRW</mrw:Nombre>
           <mrw:Telefono>622202020</mrw:Telefono>
           <mrw:Contacto>PRUEBA</mrw:Contacto>
           <mrw:ALaAtencionDe></mrw:ALaAtencionDe>
           <mrw:Observaciones>OBSERVACIONES</mrw:Observaciones>
        </mrw:DatosEntrega>
        <mrw:DatosServicio>
           <mrw:Fecha>24/08/2021</mrw:Fecha>
           <mrw:Referencia>REFERENCE</mrw:Referencia>
           <mrw:CodigoServicio>0200</mrw:CodigoServicio>
            <mrw:NumeroBultos>1</mrw:NumeroBultos>
           <mrw:Peso>2</mrw:Peso>
                <mrw:Notificaciones>
                    <mrw:NotificacionRequest>
                        <mrw:CanalNotificacion></mrw:CanalNotificacion>
                        <mrw:TipoNotificacion></mrw:TipoNotificacion>
                        <mrw:MailSMS></mrw:MailSMS>
                    </mrw:NotificacionRequest>
                </mrw:Notificaciones>
            </mrw:DatosServicio>
         </mrw:request>
      </mrw:TransmEnvio>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Usando Laravel-Soap**

```
class Test
{ 
    protected $soapWrapper;

    public function __construct(SoapWrapper $soapWrapper)
    {
       $this->soapWrapper = $soapWrapper;
    }

    public function show()
    {
      $this->soapWrapper->add('mrw', function ($service) 
      {
         $service
            ->wsdl('http://sagec-test.mrw.es/MRWEnvio.asmx?WSDL')
            ->trace(true)
            ->options([
                'CodigoFranquicia' => '003088',
                'CodigoAbonado' => '0033038',
                'CodigoDepartamento' => '',
                'UserName' => 'Usuario',
                'Password' => 'Password'
            ]);
        });

    // Without classmap
    $response = $this->soapWrapper->call('mrw.TransmEnvio', [
        'DatosRecogida' =>
            [
                'Direccion' =>
                    [
                        'CodigoTipoVia'     => '',
                        'Via'       => '',
                        'Numero' => '',
                        'Resto'   => '',
                        'CodigoPostal'     => '',
                        'Poblacion'       => '',
                        'Provincia' => '',
                        'CodigoPais'   => '',
                    ],
                'Nif' => '',
                'Nombre' => '',
                'Telefono' => '',
                'Contacto' => '',
                'Observaciones' => ''
            ],
        'DatosEntrega' =>
            [
                'Direccion' =>
                    [
                        'CodigoTipoVia' => 'CALLE',
                        'Via' => 'CORCEGA',
                        'Numero' => '102',
                        'Resto' => 'PISO 4B',
                        'CodigoPostal' => '08209',
                        'Poblacion' => 'BARCELONA',
                        'Provincia' => '',
                        'CodigoPais' => 'ES'
                    ],
                'Nif' => '',
                'Nombre' => 'PRUEBA INTEGRACION MRW',
                'Telefono' => '622202020',
                'Contacto' => 'PRUEBA',
                'ALaAtencionDe' => '',
                'Observaciones' => 'OBSERVACIONES'
            ],
        'DatosServicio' =>
            [
                'Fecha' => '24/08/2021',
                'Referencia' => 'REFERENCE',
                'CodigoServicio' => '0200',
                'NumeroBultos' => '1',
                'Peso' => '2',

                'Notificaciones' =>
                    [
                        'NotificacionRequest' =>
                            [
                                'CanalNotificacion' => '',
                                'TipoNotificacion' => '',
                                'MailSMS' => ''
                            ]
                    ]
            ]
    ]);

   var_dump($response);
}        
}
```

La cosa es, que cuando se conecta verdaderamente al servidor si he puesto algun dato mal o falta alguna informacion o lo que sea, deberia mostrar algo como esto:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
  <TransmEnvioResponse xmlns="http://www.mrw.es/">
     <TransmEnvioResult>
        <Estado>0</Estado>
        <Mensaje>1) El usuario especificado no dispone de acceso al sistema, consulte con su 
         franquicia.</Mensaje>
        <NumeroSolicitud/>
        <NumeroEnvio/>
        <Url/>
        </TransmEnvioResult>
      </TransmEnvioResponse>
   </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

Por el contrario automáticamente recibo un mensaje como este:

```
  object(stdClass)[1430]
  public 'TransmEnvioResult' => 
  object(stdClass)[1431]
  public 'Estado' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'Mensaje' => string '1) La información del usuario es incompleta.' (length=45)
  public 'NumeroSolicitud' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'NumeroEnvio' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'Url' => string '' (length=0)
```

He revisado con detenimiento y pareciera que la sección para colocar los datos de autenticación no los estuviera tomando.

Cabe destacar que he probado el servidor con SOAPUI para asegurarme que el servicio funciona y de esa manera es como les pude mostrar como es que aparecen los mensajes que debería mostrar.

Ademas, que he probado otros servidores donde no necesito clave y el servicio funciona perfectamente, el problema lo veo es cuando debo colocar credenciales.

Espero que tal vez ustedes puedan ver lo que yo no veo.

Gracias.

Comment: pregunta intentaste usando POSTMAN y verificar si la petición funciona

Comment: Hola Steven, use algo parecido a postman se llama SOAPUI

Comment: Como seria armar este mismo ejemplo pero usando la clase: SoapClient de php?